# Xcode6.4で実機ビルドをしたいのに、端末を設定するカラム？というか項目が出てこなくて困っています

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode6.4で実機ビルドをしたいのに、端末を設定するカラム？というか項目が出てこなくて困っています。(画像参照)
この状態でビルドするとシミュレーターでのビルドになってしまいます。

実機を選択したり、シミュレーターで他のデバイスを選択したいのですが、
どのようにすればよいでしょうか?
この項目の名前がわからず、ぐぐることもできない状況です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに、実機のiPhone8.4をLightningケーブルでつないでいて、
テザリングしています。
また、deployment targetは8.4にしています。
ついさっきまで家で作業していた時は問題なく表示されていました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: スキームを選ぶ欄ですので、英語では、scheme menu、scheme editor、scheme pop-up 等と呼ばれるようです。[About the Scheme Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

ツールバー上のメニューは、よく使う機能の一部を手軽に使えるようにしてあるものなので、同じ機能はメニューバーの中にもあります。

「Product」→「Destination」で同じことができますので、ひとまずそちらを使われてはどうでしょうか？

同じ現象を見かけたことはあるのですが、ずっとそのままの状態になって困った、ということは特になかった気がして、マイナーな不具合として無視していました。もし再現手順や改善手順が分かれば教えて下さい ;-)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
確かに前にも出なかったことがあるような気がします。
とりいそぎ、他のバージョンのXcodeいれなおして回避しました。

Answer (score 0):

気づいたら、こちらのXcode6.4もその「カラム」が消えてしまってます。OS X 10.11 El CapitanとXcode6.4の組み合わせで、この障害が起きるのではないでしょうか？
すでに対処法は紹介されてますが、その他の対処法として、Windowメニュー＞Devicesで、シミュレータを含めたデバイス一覧を表示し、選択する方法もあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※Xcode7とXcode6.4両方インストールしている影響もあるのかな？

Comment: お、言われてみると私もEl Capitanにアップデート済みです。6.4はもう使わないので、7.0.1をいれて対応しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ウインドウの幅が狭くて省略されてるだけでは。
横に広げると出てくると思いますが。